# How can I download a video from the web to my iPad?

Tags: video, ipad

There's an m4v video for download on the web that I'd like to watch offline on my iPad. This is the process I know will work:

1. Open link in web browser on my laptop
2. Download video to my laptop
3. Stick video in iTunes
4. Connect my iPad to my laptop
5. Sync
6. Disconnect iPad from laptop
7. Watch offline

This is what I *want* to do:

1. Open link in web browser on my iPad
2. Download video to my iPad
3. Watch offline

Is there currently a way to do this?

Comment: What kind of video? Is it YouTube? Is it Flash?

Comment: @timothymh Just a straight-up .m4v file stored on a remote server. No Flash or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in MobileSafari on the iPad.  There may be an app for it somewhere on the App Store, though.

Comment: Is there a proof link?

Answer (score 0):

You can get an app called Azul that replicates that functionality.

If you jailbreak it you can get Safari Download Manager, but without jailbreaking your iPad the only way is through apps.

Answer (score -1):

You may refer to this guide, it's regarding [how to download website video to computer](http://www.reviewstown.com/how-to-download-convert-website-flash-video.html) for free. It works pretty well for me.