# Download video via Web links to iPhone

Tags: iphone, safari, video

Sometimes I want to download files straight from the link on a website as it can be done on a desktop computer. I'm not talking about streaming video sites like YouTube, just plain [href](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) links designed to be downloaded with something like right-click and "Download linked file as..." on a PC or Mac.

On Android, for example, I can tap on a video link and have the MP4 file saved locally in a downloads folder so I can watch it offline. So I am wondering how I can do the same on an iPhone (running iOS 12)?

I've seen an [answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250066526) on the Apple Discussion forum that involves clicking on the share button in Safari. One of the actions is download to Dropbox (which I haven't managed to get working yet) but I cannot see "save to Files", at least for videos, which is what I need.

Also tried two apps that have an integrated browser that lets you download the files when tapping the link. I've found them to be extremely unreliable as I couldn't get them to finish downloading a full video, so I gave up on them.

From an old similar [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/15968/329120) for the iPad I'm guessing it's not possible, but I just want to be sure if there any good solutions that I'm missing, or will have to develop my own application or switch to Android? Seems like a basic functionality to me.

Comment: It's the same functionality that you've see with "Save to Dropbox".  Have you tried Siri Shortcuts?  There's many custom shortcuts that people have made to save to Files.

Comment: No I haven't. Just looked at https://support.apple.com/en-ie/HT209055 now and don't see how that would help. What is missing is a "Save to files" activity, but I don't know yet how to add this. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: If you have the Files app on your device then you should see that in the Sharing extenstion.  It might be hidden so see if you can turn it on.

Comment: It’s definitely not there, even if I tap “more”. But I can see it if I do “share” on Pages, for example.

Comment: I love that you included w3schools - I wonder if any of the sites you are browsing don’t just work follow the download file guidance. My initial hunch is those sites are making it hard to just download? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_download_link.asp

Comment: I don’t think it’s the website at all (suprememastertv.com) since it has worked with Android. Anyway, thankfully with the new iOS release it works fine with the download manager on iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari is getting a download manager in iOS 13 which is due to release sometime later this fall.

- [iOS 13 Hands-on: Safari Finally Gets a Download Manager](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2019/06/ios-13-hands-on-safari-download-manager.html)

> [image]

- [New Safari Download Manager feature in iOS 13 will make you more productive](https://appletoolbox.com/2019/06/Safari-download-manager-iOS13-iPadOS)

> [image]

Comment: No no no, they should switch to Android. Didn’t you see all the clues in the question?

Comment: @bmike Sarcasm? 

Comment: Never, the internet doesn’t allow for that and neither does this site. 

Comment: By the way, this now also shows on Apple's official iOS13 preview: "**Downloads folder**:
A new downloads folder gives you a central place to access your web downloads and attachments from Safari and Mail."